# Return in try catch block. Correcty?

Tags: java, exception, try-catch

Is it possible to make something like that?:

```
try {
...
} catch (exception){

    return; // this is most important thing here. In catch block only "return"

}
```

Can I handle exception in this way - use only "return;"?
It works fine, but I would like to know is it correct?

Comment: notice that you say can I "handle" the exceptions this way, but you are not really handling it in *any* way...

Answer (score 3):

This way you are ignoring the `Exception`, is it *really* want you want? It all depends on your context - it might be safe to do this (I doubt it, but hey, it's your code). Generally when some Exceptions happens - you should react, not by simply `return`ing, but logging, defaulting (rarely a good option), retrying, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that's actually a valid use case. There are many valid reasons to return in the catch block, one of them being returning default values:

```
try {
    return service.getData();
} catch (SocketTimeoutException ex) {
    logTimeout(ex);
    return getCachedData();
}
```

Comment: Note, though, that Ernest a) includes a `logTimeout(ex)` and b) returns an alternative result. Completely ignoring the exception is rarely a good idea (but yeah, you can).

Answer (score 1):

It is correct syntax but as per java coding standards we must not swallow exceptions rather handle them in catch block or rethrow it with proper message

Answer (score 0):

if you do something like this

```
public void someMethod(){
    try{
    ...
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return;
    }
}
```

You lose your exception.It's a bad practice, because if something goes wrong - you even won't be able to understand what's going wrong.
Better ways

- print error message to logs
- rethrow this exception or your custom exception and process it on the next levels